# Testing PDO Error Handling: How to Force a Database Connection Error?

Tags: php, mysql, testing, pdo, error-handling

Is there any way to force a database connection error so I can test my PHP code's error handling? We know that for PDO there's a huge risk that improper error handling can cause a full back trace to be displayed on-screen, possibly revealing the database's username and password (as warned on [php.net » pdo connections](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)).

I've been trying to intentionally force this to happen (by renaming to fictional database tables, etc.) but I haven't yet been able to get the result. Are there any other ways of simulating database problems?

I have Cpanel access on a shared host running Apache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply provide incorrect credentials. Renaming tables would be of little help because tables are not involved in the connection. Change `host`, `username` or `password` instead.

> improper error handling can cause a full back trace to be displayed on-screen,

That's a very proper concern.

However, the solution is very simple

- in order to avoid displaying *any* errors on-screen, just tell PHP to do so, setting `display_errors` configuration directive to 0.
- in order to avoid leaking the database credentials into a stack trace (even if not displayed, getting into the logs is not much better), just catch the exception and throw a brand new one as it will effectively erase the stack trace and create a new empty one, just like it shown in my article, [How to connect with PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql)

Basically you need

```
try {
     $pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
```